# The current path, imageupload, didn't match any of these, Page not Found Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, image-classification

I am new to Django and I am trying to build an image classifier app, I just tried building the app but I am getting this error, how may I resolve it?

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/imageupload
Using the URLconf defined in imageclassifier.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

imageupload ^$ [name='home']
admin/
The current path, imageupload, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

These are all changes I made in my app:
This is the views.py file in imgUpload app

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

This is the urls.py file in imageUpload app

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('^$', views.home, name ='home'),
]
```

And this is the urls.py in the Imageclassifier folder:

```
"""imageclassifier URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""

    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path,include
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('imageupload', include('imgUpload.urls')),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        
    ]
```

Also, I have added a home.html file in the templates folder. How may I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest django path methods, You do not need to use ^$ in your path. Simply remove that ^$ from your path and it will work fine.

Comment: Should I leave it empty?